# Unity 2D: How to make patrolling AI turn around?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D platformer in Unity, and made a patrolling enemy with code from a tutorial video. The enemy basically moves randomly to different spots in the scene. But how can I make the sprite turn around?

This is my code so far. I've tried with different approaches, but not getting the expected behavior.

```
public float speed = 10f;
private float waitTime;
public float startWaitTime = 1f;

public Transform[] moveSpots;
private int randomSpot;

private bool moving = true;
private bool m_FacingRight = true;

void Start()
{
    waitTime = startWaitTime;
    randomSpot = Random.Range(0, moveSpots.Length);
}

void Update()
{
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, moveSpots[randomSpot].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, moveSpots[randomSpot].position) < 0.2f)
    {

        //Debug.Log(m_FacingRight);

        // if (moving.x > 0 && !m_FacingRight)
        // {
        //     Debug.Log("moving right");
        //     Flip();
        // }
        // else if (moving.x < 0 && m_FacingRight)
        // {
        //     Debug.Log("moving left");
        //     Flip();
        // }

        if (waitTime <= 0)
        {
            //moving = true;
            randomSpot = Random.Range(0, moveSpots.Length);
            waitTime = startWaitTime;
        }
        else
        {
            //moving = false;
            waitTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}

//private void Flip()
//{
    //m_FacingRight = !m_FacingRight;
    //transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
//}
```

**********************************EDIT****************************************

I ended up with this for the enemy script movement

```html
private bool facingRight = true;
    private Rigidbody2D rigidBody2D;
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

    public Vector2 speed = new Vector2(10, 0);
    public Vector2 direction = new Vector2(1, 0);

    private void Awake()
    {
        rigidBody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.CompareTag("Wall") || collision.collider.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            direction = Vector2.Scale(direction, new Vector2(-1, 0));
        }

        if (!collision.collider.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            if (!facingRight)
            {
                Flip();
            }
            else if (facingRight)
            {
                Flip();
            }
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector2 movement = new Vector2(speed.x * direction.x, 0);
        movement *= Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(movement);
    }

    private void Flip()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        if (!facingRight)
        {
            spriteRenderer.flipX = true;
        }
        else if (facingRight)
        {
            spriteRenderer.flipX = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `but not getting the expected behavior.` What was expected? What happened instead?

Comment: What is the value of `startWaitTime`? Do you realise you aren't actually calling `Flip`?

Comment: I expect the sprite to turn around, once it starts moving towards a "moveSpot" in the opposite direction.

Comment: Che k this out https://answers.unity.com/questions/1117035/how-to-flip-2d-character-walk-movement.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your Flip function to

```
private void Flip()
{
   m_FacingRight = !m_FacingRight;
   GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
}
```

Also, if you're looking for a reference, I made a platformer in Unity that includes enemy patrolling https://github.com/sean244/Braid-Clone

Answer (score 0):

In a sidescroller, an easy way to achieve this is to use [SpriteRenderer.flipX](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-flipX.html).

For instance, if you want to flip X when the velocity is negative:

```
var sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
sr.flipX = velocity.x < 0;
```